# Xcode shows a "Expected declaration" error with any variable put in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Been getting this error whenever I have a variable or pretty much anything else. For example here I put cpuString and when I called it I got the error

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cpuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var coolerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var moBoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ramLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gpuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var psuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var caseLabel: UILabel!

    var cpuString = ""

    cpuSting = "Intel i5"  // Here is where I got the Expected declaration 
}
```

No idea whats causing this. Funny thing is that Xcode is ignoring everything. When I try to do something with the labels it's like there not even there. When I start typing and the auto complete suggestions for things to put in it doesn't have my variables or anything else listed.

Comment: You can combine the two statements to declare the variable and assign it an initial value - `var cpuSting = "Intel i5"`, but you can't have arbitrary code, such as the assignment `cpuSting = "Intel i5"` outside of a function.

Comment: Did you tried cleaning cache and Clean project and build again ? it happens sometime that Xcode doesn't show any error try Cleaning and building again if still succeeds select another class from list and re open your ViewController where error should show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move that assignment either to declaration or into valid scope:

1:

```
var cpuSting = "Intel i5"
```

2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cpuSting = "Intel i5"
}
```

What you do in your code is essentially attempting to make an assignment in an improper place. If you declare a variable, then just declare it with required initial value. If you want to re-assign a value, then just do that in the right place, such as in instance method scope like `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Seems to work. I'm new to swift and I always left the viewDidLoad at the bottom of the view controller. Why is it now that I have to put stuff in the ViewDidLoad when it worked fine before?

Comment: Not sure if I understand... Swift allows you to set needed initial value on declaration stage. In Objective-C, developer was forced to make initial assignments in places such as `viewDidLoad` or `init`, this is no longer the case for Swift. So, you don't _have_ to put it to `viewDidLoad`, it's only that you can, if there's a need to make secondary (consequent) assignments. For initialization `var cpuSting = "Intel i5"` is enough.